# Facebook FBSDKAppInviteContent - Missing App Link URL

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Do you need to have your own website with `meta` tags for your app link url to use the `FBSDKAppInviteContent` and `FBSDKAppInviteDialog` to invite friends?. If I put just the app link url there,

It shows an error saying something like

> Missing App Link URL
>   The app link used with this invite does not contain an Android or iOS URL. Developers are required to enter a URL for at least one platform.

I'm using `facebook-sdk` iOS and also `fbsdksharekit`. Does anyone know how to solve this error or warning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, You have to add meta tags of your app link url in your website.

---

**iOS**

*As an example, let's say you've got a page located at:*

http://example.com/applinks

*In that page you need to add some metadata to describe what app will handle it:*

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="example://applinks" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <!-- Other headers -->
</head>
<!-- Other HTML content -->
</html>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to verify, what should I put on al:ios:url? It says in facebook docs that it is "A custom URL that will be used to launch your app". So what's that url suppose to be, does it have a pattern or where should I make that url?

Comment: Hmm I think it's not because it will have an error in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ when checking the meta tags for the url and it says that "A custom URL that will be used to launch your app" so I guess it's not a url to open an app store.

Comment: No , I have checked that with existing iOS app URL and it is working fine mate!  For testing just go to  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/  and put your appstore URL in the "Input URL" box,  and click on "Fetch New Scrap Information". You will get all the info out there.

Comment: There will be no error on the object debugger but you can't use directly the app store url in FBSDKAppInviteContent as you have said I need to put my website something like this [[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] initWithAppLinkURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"http://www.mywebsite.com"l]]; with the meta tags but putting your appstore URL in al:ios:url meta tag will result to an error when checking it in the object debugger or can you tell me what's your al:ios:url like when using it for an ios app?

Comment: Nvm found how to do it here. http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html ., Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to host these or don't have a website, you can use Facebook's hosted link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api or a deep linking tool like https://branch.io

Answer (score 8):

For those who want know and asking how does it work, appLinkUrl is **not the url of your app** in the market. Here's the way I did this.

- You need to make your own appLinkUrl and put it in your
  info.plist(see:http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)
  that you'll be using for deepLinking.
- Then after you declare it on your info.plist, you must have at least
  an html web page where you can put the meta tags for the appLinks of
  ios or android(https://applinks.org). Take note the the appLinkUrl that you have put on your info.plist should be the same on your meta property="al:ios:url
- Debug your website url and check your meta tags using facebook url debugger. Press "Fetch new scrape information" to update the meta tags for any changes on it.
- Use the link of your webpage that has the meta tags and use it like on the sample
  on facebook docs

  > FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
  >   content.appLinkURL = [NSURL
  >   URLWithString:@"your_website_link_with_metatags"];
- Just make sure your meta tags have the right information and that's
  it!

Comment: Shane, can you please add complete meta data with your answer. Yes, you don't need to add real data with it. But it'll be helpful to me. I'm still getting error when inviting to my friends.

Comment: Ok, now I'm no longer getting error. Even it show me a checkmark after successful invitation but that invitation notification would never show in Facebook. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Does your facebook app configured properly on the developers.facebook.com? Is "Single Sign On" mark as YES, also make the others YES too.

Comment: Does it work in sandbox environment? My app is already on appstore. for next version I've enabled deep linking and now no error occurs but invitation is not sent.

Comment: sandbox should have nothing to do with it, Try to check the steps again.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers it is also nice to know that you can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to refresh your applink url's scrape information. If you initially placed incorrect values in the meta tags it will not be refreshed right away unless you go to that link and explicitly refresh it.

Comment: Thanks for this one... tooked me forever to understand why the cache did not update!

Comment: You literally saved my life. +1 so much.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Facebook App Links Hosting API will be of help

"If your application doesn't have a website for content you want to share to Facebook, you don't have public web URLs which you can annotate to support App Links.

For these types of apps, Facebook provides an App Links Hosting API that will host App Links for you. With the Hosting API you can create and manage your App Links for all the mobile environments you support."

Source:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api

Answer (score 1):

Adding meta tags would solve this, this is snippet of html from app link created via FB. Fb is adding some extra meta tags on it's app link url page, and it also redirects direct to itunes if opened on a browser.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>app name</title>
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="your fb app id" />
 <meta property="al:ios:url" content="Your app link url" />
 <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="your app name" />
 <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="your app id" />
 <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/redirectToContent?id=your app store id" />
</head>
<body>
 Redirecting...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sushil you need to create a html resource file and add it to your webpage don't need to provide extended link to this page in your website, and then in your code where you add app link provide link to the page that has this code. It will work fine.